# Ember query-params-new for multiple objects

Tags: ember.js

I'm using query parameters for paging and filtering. `query-params-new` provides a relatively convenient way to manage array returned from `route.model`.

But now I've got a page with a single object (f.e. group) as model, and a list of dependent objects (f.e. users in group), displayed at the same time. List should have paging.

The problem is that I dont know where I should put request for the list. Query parameters, needed for constructing list query, are only available in `route.model` method and in `controller` as properties.

Now I'm trying to find a *proper* way to get both object and list with paging in same route/controller. None of the ways I could invent, like combining them both into single object in `route.model` or requesting list from controller's `observes` function, seem right and clean. Currently I've stopped on saving query parameters in `route.model` and using them in `route.setupController` for second request, but that is a hack obviously.

I'm just looking for the right approach, without fighting framework.

Comment: Could you provide self-contained example?